# Fetch Records for a particular date from Timestamp field

Tags: java, mysql, date, timestamp, jpql

I have a field of type Timestamp in my MySQL database. I want to list all records for a particular date, let's say, 18/08/2016.
 I want to write a JPQL query for this.

I tried to use `TRUNC()`, `to_DATE()` , `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, `myTimestamp = '2016-08-18'` an a few other methods but none of them seem to be working.

Please suggest a method for this.

Comment: Check with a time then it works, like this myTimestamp = '2016-08-18 15:53:57'

Answer (score 1):

1. `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` fields represent both a date (like 2016-08-18) and a time (like 07:43:20).   This means that `myTimestamp = '2016-08-18'` is very unlikely to come out `true`. It only comes out true if `myTimestamp` has the precise value `2016-08-18 00:00:00`.
2. When you represent date / time values as text, you must use the ISO format, which looks like this:

   `2016-08-18 07:43:20`

If you want to use differently formatted text, you can, but you must convert it [using `STR_TO_DATE()` in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). These conversion functions are generally not standardized between different makes and models of RDBMS servers.

3. To get all the timestamp values in a day, you need to search a range. This is the best way to do that:

`WHERE myTimestamp >= DATE('2016-08-18')
   AND myTimestamp < DATE('2016-08-18') + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

This method of searching, while a little more verbose than others, allows MySQL to use an index on myTimestamp. If your table has many rows, this can save astonishing amounts of time.

Date and time processing is mostly not standardized between makes and models of database server.

**Edit** The query in the comment here is malformed. It says:

```
SELECT b.name, b.publisher, sum(p.copies) 
  FROM PurchaseEntity p, BookEntity b  /* old-timey comma join! */
 WHERE p.bookEntity.bookId = b.bookId  /* wrong! */
   AND date(p.purchaseTime)= '2016-08-18'
 group by b.bookId  /* nonstandard! */
```

You're using `p.bookEntity.bookId` in a `WHERE` clause. That's not right.

You're using MySQL's [nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) as well.

Your query probably should say this. You should test this query with a SQL client program before attempting to build it into your Java program.

```
SELECT b.name, b.publisher, sum(p.copies) 
  FROM PurchaseEntity p, 
  JOIN BookEntity b ON p.bookId = b.bookId 
   AND date(p.purchaseTime)= '2016-08-18'
 group by b.name, b.publisher
```

Comment: It's giving the { <expression>, <operator>, AND, GROUP, HAVING, IS expected, got '(' } error when I use the DATE function. Removing the space before the parenthesis isn't working either.

Comment: You may  wish to ask another question showing the *entire* query. Also, the message you mention doesn't look like a MySQL syntax error message. Are you sure you're using MySQL and not some other database server?

Comment: The database is MySQL but I am using Hibernate JPA. Basically i am writing a hibernate query.

String bookQuery=
                "SELECT b.name, b.publisher, sum(p.copies) FROM PurchaseEntity p, BookEntity b " +
                "WHERE p.bookEntity.bookId = b.bookId "    +
                "AND date(p.purchaseTime)= '2016-08-18' "     +
                "group by b.bookId";
Query BookQuery = entityManager.createQuery(bookQuery);
List< Object[] > resultListByUser = UserQuery.getResultList();

Answer (score 0):

Use the date() MySQL function to get the date part of timestamp or a datetime field:

```
select * from yourtable where date(timestamp_field)= '2016-08-18'
```

Comment: Whenever I am using any function, there is an error appearing at the '(', stating that <expression>, <operator>, AND, GROUP, HAVING, IS expected, got '(' .

Comment: In MySQL there may not be spaces between function names and the parenthesis following them.  `MAX(col)` is valid. `MAX (col)` is not. It's just one of those little quirks.

Comment: @Random it is somewhat difficult to provide any meaningful answer without knowing any details. The queries that Ollie and myself created work in MySQL.